# react-router component state functions not fired in order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

Here is a log of what is happening, while I navigate around my app a parent component is mounted a second time but never unmounted. This causes issues because I'm changing redux state in these functions:

```
2016-12-12 14:06:01.160 events.js:33  EVENTS componentWillMount
2016-12-12 14:06:01.257 events.js:38  EVENTS componentWillReceiveProps
2016-12-12 14:06:01.534 events.js:38  EVENTS componentWillReceiveProps
2016-12-12 14:06:01.537 forms.js:34   FORMS componentWillMount
2016-12-12 14:06:01.537 forms.js:20   FETCHING!!!!!
2016-12-12 14:06:01.541 forms.js:52   render
2016-12-12 14:06:01.591 forms.js:39   FORMS componentWillReceiveProps
2016-12-12 14:06:01.592 forms.js:52   render
2016-12-12 14:06:01.771 forms.js:39   FORMS componentWillReceiveProps
2016-12-12 14:06:01.774 layout.js:29  EVENTAPP componentWillMount
2016-12-12 14:06:01.806 forms.js:34   FORMS componentWillMount
```

So it fires an "unmount" and tries to render which doesn't work since my state assumes that container is unmounted now.  You can see it gets mounted a second time *AFTER* its child is is mounted?

Here is the structure of the router/component tree:

```
<Route component={FormsContainer}>
    <Route component={EventAppLayout}>
        <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="reports" component={ReportsContainer}>
            <IndexRoute component={Reports}/>
            <Route path=":reportId" component={RunReportContainer} />
            <Route path=":reportId/:subReportId" component={RunReportContainer} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="attendees" component={AttendeesContainer}>
            <IndexRoute component={Attendees} />
            <Route path=":attendeeId" component={AttendeesNav}>
                <Route path="overview" component={AttendeeDetails} />
                <Route path="answers" component={AttendeeAnswers}/>
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Route>
```

The FormsContainer is the one that is mounting/unmounting.   I expected it to never unmount/mount when transitioning between ReportsContainer and AttendeesContainer since it is the parent container for both of them?

So my questions are:

- Why is the parent container unmounting/remounting at all?
- Why does it mount again without unmounting first?
- How do I fix this?